# Why Is the Simpson's backyard tree blue in 'Grampa vs. Sexual Inadequacy' (S06E10)?

Tags: continuity, the-simpsons

[image]

[image]

While the show makes use of pastel colors, I don't remember this level of liberties taken with domestic plants. This tree on the Simpsons' yard looks standard in every other episode of the hand-animated run (seasons 1-13) I can remember. Could this be a coloring error?

The image is from the season six NTSC DVD.

Comment: I watched the episode recently and skimmed through again, but to confirm: Homer never poured the elixir on the roots of the tree?

Comment: I don't recall seeing this one, but based on the title, the blue & the apparent size of the tree, wouldn't it just be a viagra joke?

Comment: I recommend changing the question to something like "Why is this tree blue?". Because you're wondering whether it's a colouring error, your question could be closed for trivia because of its intention. However, as Tetsujin points out, there could be a good reason for the colour.

Comment: The episode aired several years before Viagra came on the market, so it isn’t that.

Comment: @JimMurtha - Point, though it was invented in the late 80s but took a long time to be certified. I honestly can't remember when the media first started talking about it.

Comment: Viagra was approved in 1998, but it was discovered in 1983. Simpsons Season 6 Episode 3 was first aired on September 25, 1994. So, yes, a 'little blue pill' making 'things grow' allusion was definitely a possibility.